# What is the correct term when calling a widget from xml in Android?

Tags: android, android-inflate

I'm still very new to Android, but I am trying to keep up by using tutorials on YouTube. A bunch of people throw around the phrase "inflate the xml". I started to use this phrase as well, and I feel as though I'm not doing it right.

The only time I say "inflate the xml" is when telling someone to write the code to use a widget from the xml in java code.

So if I see a button on someones layout, with the id of `button01`, and I tell them to "inflate the xml" I expect `Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);`

Is this wrong of me?

**EDIT:**
It seems as though this is not the correct phrase. Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Inflating" a layout refers to the process of having the Android framework convert a layout in XML format into objects corresponding to the different views in the layout.

To "inflate" a layout you need:

- a layout in XML format

  res/layout/main.xml
- access to an inflator object

  LayoutInflater inflater = 
          (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

You then need to run the inflation on the layout

```
   View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main)
```

After that you can access the objects using "findViewById"

```
    Button mybutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button01);
```

The Activity class provides a helper method which both gets the inflator and inflates the layout

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

When using the "setContentView" method, the activity sets a default view which is used when calling "findViewById"

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. When someone says to inflate a layout (or as you say, inflate the xml), the piece of code that generally comes to mind is something like:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
```

Another way to obtain the inflater would be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You would then proceed with

```
Button mybutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button01);
```

Comment: If my program consisted of 1 layout, 1 button, and 1 activity, what would be the point of `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout);`

That line is not needed to write `Button mybutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button01);` is it?

Have I been doing something fundamentally incorrect this entire time?

Comment: No, you doing `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)` has the same effect and inflates it for the `Activity` you will be using it for. The above code is for inflating other/additional layouts.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity... why would you want to have more than one layout?

Comment: @EGHDK In any case where you have more than one way of displaying data or more than one view etc.  Think of a contacts application.  There would be a contact list, and a contact details view at least.  Each of these would need their own layouts

Comment: One place where I inflate a layout is in a custom Adapter for `ListView`s. The use case for me has been to inflate when I use a layout outside of an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);, you are basically casting the button you created in your code to the button you defined in the xml.

I don't really know if "inflating" is the correct term. I think of it as a way to link what you have placed in your xml layout with your functionality you have defined in your java code.