# Why am I getting a null value for this linearlayout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update this `LinearLayout` but I am getting a `null` value. Can someone tell me why?

Java:

```
public class MenuTabFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String TAG = MenuTabFragment.class.getSimpleName();



    private int[] menuButtons = { R.drawable.breakfast_btn,
            R.drawable.lunch_btn, R.drawable.dinner_btn, R.drawable.drinks_btn,
            R.drawable.appetizers_btn, R.drawable.dessert_btn,
            R.drawable.sides_btn };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menutabslayout, container, false);
            //this is a null value
        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menuTabs);
        Log.i(TAG, linLayout + ": linLayout" );
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuTabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuTabs);`

Comment: Great code! You should add a sentence or two explaining why this works.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thank you so much! Will accept as soon as I can!

Comment: See this for more infos : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217454/what-is-the-correct-term-when-calling-a-widget-from-xml-in-android